# How to iterate over 2 dissimilar pandas dataframes to modify one of them based on a condition satisfied by the other?

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes, df1 and df2. `df1['start_times']` contains the start of an event. `df1['flag']` and `df1['flag_times']` only contain NaNs.

df2 contains some flags that are displayed either at location left (l) or right (r) at certain time points given in `df2['flag_times']`. I want to insert each `df2['flag_times']` in `df1['flag_times']` in appropriate rows such that

`df1.at[row, 'start_times'] <= df2.at[key_count, 'flag_times'] < df1.at[row+1, 'start_times']` where *row* is an index iterating over df1 and *key_count* over df2.

If this condition is satisfied, then `df1.at[row, 'flag_times'] = df2.at[i, 'flag_times']` and `df1.at[row, 'flag'] = df2.at[i, 'flag']`.

More elaborated answer with a code that I have tried is below:

```
times = random.sample(range(1, 10000), 10)
times.sort()
flag_times = random.sample(range(times[0], times[-1]), 2)
flag_times.sort()
flags = np.tile(['l', 'r'], 2).sort()

df1 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(times, np.repeat(np.nan, s), np.repeat(np.nan, s))), 
                   columns = ['start_times', 'flag', 'flag_times'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(flag_times, flags)), 
                   columns = ['flag', 'flag_times'])
```

df1:

| start_times | flag | flag_times |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 235 | NaN | NaN |
| 457 | NaN | NaN |
| 950 | NaN | NaN |
| 1902 | NaN | NaN |

df2:

| flag | flag_times |
| --- | --- |
| l | 390 |
| r | 1000 |

All the values in `df1['start_times']` are in the increasing order. df2 contains some flags and the times at which they were displayed. I want to take each item `df2['flag_times']` and insert the corresponding time in in `df1['flag_times']` such that it is more than or equal to the `df1['times']` in that row but less than the next `df1['times']` in the next row. Rest of the rows should remain NaN

In the example above, '`df1` should look like this:

| start_times | flag | flag_times |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 235 | l | 390 |
| 457 | NaN | NaN |
| 950 | r | 1000 |
| 1902 | NaN | NaN |

I have written the following code:

```
row = 0
key_count = 0

while row < len(df1)-1:
    while key_count < len(df2):
        if df1.at[row, 'start_times'] <= df2.at[key_count, 'flag_times'] <= df1.at[row+1, 'start_times']:
            df1.at[row, 'flag_times'] = df2.at[key_count, 'flag_times']
            df1.at[row, 'flag'] = df2.at[key_count, 'flag']
            print('======================================')
            key_count += 1
            break

    row += 1
```

am not sure what I am doing wrong but it is not working. How else should I go about this keeping in mind that both of the dataframes are huge?

Answer (score 0):

#### Annotated Code

```
# Find the indices in start_times where the values from the 
# flag_times should be inserted to maintain the sorting order
ix = np.searchsorted(df1['start_times'], df2['flag_times'])

# Condition to identify the indices which are out of bounds
m = ~np.isin(ix, [0, len(df1)])

# Remove the out of bound indices
ix = ix[m] - 1

# Filter the rows in df2 which satisfy the condition
# Use set_axis to reindex and join back with start_times
result = df1[['start_times']].join(df2[m].set_axis(ix))
```

#### Result

```
   start_times flag  flag_times
0          235    l       390.0
1          457  NaN         NaN
2          950    r      1000.0
3         1902  NaN         NaN
```